# avoid RSA key fingerprint while running bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am using Opscode chef, for my infrastructure management and code deployment. But I am facing a issue, whenever I run bundle install from recipe it asks for RSA key fingerprint and expects input. But the recipe fails to continue further. Some how I need to remove this RSA fingerprint during bundle install or bundle update. How do I remove it using recipe/cookbook to deploy ruby on rails application.

Comment: Why does it ask for a fingerprint? I use `bundle install` all the time and have never come across it. Maybe something particular to your `Gemfile` (such as an alternate gem source)?

Comment: Yes its a alternative gem source, it pulls for github where I use bitbucket, I have used ssh wrapper for bit bucket not for github so it asks for RSA fingerprint

Comment: Have you tried creating an entry on `~/.ssh/config` for `github.com` using `StrickHostKeyChecking No`?

Comment: Nope, how to I do it. Can you be explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create these files (where `<bundle_user>` is the user that will run the `bundle` commands or the attribute that references it):

```
### recipes/ssh_config.rb
directory "#{<bundle_user>}/.ssh" do
  mode 00755
  owner <bundle_user>
end

cookbook_file "#{bundle_user}/.ssh/config" do
  source "ssh_config"
  owner <bundle_user>
  mode 00644
end


### files/default/ssh_config
Host github.com
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Then, before the `deploy` resource runs, `include_recipe "your_cookbook::ssh_config"`. This will disable the SSH fingerprint verification for `github.com`.

Note that this has security implications (notably, it makes it easier to suffer a MITM attack).